# Installing real time patch for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, realtime

I am trying to install Real time patch on ubuntu 20.04 I followed many steps and for each trial it took about 4 hours to complete. Unfortunately none of these trials worked (in the links below).
I really appreciate if you could advice me with exact steps to follow as I am new guy in using Linux.
Thank you very much.

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Building-Realtime-rt_preempt-kernel-for-ROS-2.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu/51709420#51709420

https://hmenn.github.io/pages/UbuntuRT_patch.html
https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2016/04/msg00579.html

John

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build the PREEMPT-RT kernel on Ubuntu 20.04 mostly based on [this guide](https://chenna.me/blog/2020/02/23/how-to-setup-preempt-rt-on-ubuntu-18-04/) as follows:

```
sudo apt install build-essential git libssl-dev libelf-dev flex bison
```

Download kernel source and patch for that version:

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.4.143.tar.xz
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.4/patch-5.4.143-rt64-rc2.patch.xz
```

Unpack and apply patches:

```
tar -xf linux-5.4.143.tar.xz
cd linux-5.4.143
xzcat ../patch-5.4.143-rt64-rc2.patch.xz | patch -p1
```

Configure, and when asked for **Preemption Model** select the **Fully Preemptible Kernel**. Accept the default value for the rest:

```
cp /boot/config-5.4.0-81-generic .config
make oldconfig
```

Edit the `.config` file and change `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="debian/canonical-certs.pem"` to `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""`

Build kernel:

```
make -j8 deb-pkg
```

Install the generated packages, and reboot your system.

```
sudo dpkg -i ../linux-headers-5.4.143-rt64-rc2_5.4.143-rt64-rc2-1_amd64.deb ../linux-image-5.4.143-rt64-rc2_5.4.143-rt64-rc2-1_amd64.deb ../linux-libc-dev_5.4.143-rt64-rc2-1_amd64.deb
```

After reboot you should be able to see something like this:

```
# uname -a
Linux vod 5.4.143-rt64-rc2 #1 SMP PREEMPT_RT Tue Sep 7 20:19:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The [guide](https://chenna.me/blog/2020/02/23/how-to-setup-preempt-rt-on-ubuntu-18-04/) suggests a few other steps but I haven't tested them yet.

Comment: It is interesting to do: `make menuconfig` and search for PREEMPT_RT and set it to “Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT)” if that is what you want. Otherwise you do not get the benefits of PREEMP_RT