# Unable to boot RT kernel at grub advance option after RT patch installation

Tags: patch, realtime

I have successfully installed the rt patch follow the guide from [Installing real time patch for Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349568/installing-real-time-patch-for-ubuntu-20-04)
.

At the grub boot option, I am able to see the 5.19-generic and 5.19-rt options. when I enter 5.19-rt option, it will hang and shows a long list of errors, one that I caught was
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) similar to
[Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0) . My set up is DELL desktop and Ubuntu dual boot. pls assist, thank you!
I can boot all the kernel versions that I have installed except the ones with rt. The rt versions are also shown in cd /boot -> ls.

I have tried updating my nVidia driver, update grub and sudo update-initramfs -u -k .

Comment: Every thing I can find says only the 5.15 kernel is a Ubuntu RT kernel that has been tested. You can see this web site for more info https://ubuntu.com/engage/an-introduction-to-real-time-linux-part-i

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/simply-impossible-to-use-an-nvidia-card-on-a-real-time-kernel-no-musician-can-use-nvidia/34947/3

Hi, could this be the reason?

Comment: Will post my solution tmr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Dell set up,

1. Go to Bio setup, under SATA configuration, select AHCI save and restart.
2. Boot your boot-able kernel version, go to terminal,
   enter sudo gedit /etc/default/grub,
   edit the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line="quite splash" to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
3. Under "Software & Updates", go to Additional Drivers and select "Using Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-(510 or your latest model)(propriety, tested)" and apply changes if you have not done so.
4. Reboot and select your RT kernel under advance options for ubuntu. Good luck!

*Note that once you select AHCI, you might not be able to boot windows for my case, rmb to switch back to RAID ON mode for SATA Configuration mode.

'Sauce': [https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/#:~:text=Update%20your%20system%20and%20install,while%20using%20these%20proprietary%20drivers.](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/#:%7E:text=Update%20your%20system%20and%20install,while%20using%20these%20proprietary%20drivers.)